# How do I convert a UTF-8 String into an array of bytes in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm creating a Redis client and would like to create a byte array for sending to the Redis server. To issue commands to the server, I need to convert Dart's UTF-8 strings into a bytes which can be written to a socket.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import [dart:utf](http://api.dartlang.org/utf.html) and use its [encodeUtf8](http://api.dartlang.org/utf.html#encodeUtf8) function. There is actually a existing redis client for Dart [here](https://github.com/financeCoding/redis-dart) which makes use of these functions.

Comment: Thanks Lars, that's very helpful. I'll try that out with the socket connection and see how it goes.

Answer (score 51):

For Dart >1.0 this is now done with the convert library.

```
import 'dart:convert';
List<int> bytes = utf8.encode("Some data");
print(bytes) //[115, 111, 109, 101, 32, 100, 97, 116, 97]
```

Comment: UTF8 is deprecated sind Dart 2. But it was just renamed to utf8: List<int> bytes = utf8.encode("Some data");

Comment: I encoded the some Chinese character and put it into a pdf file and print it from printer. it only shows numbers. May I know how to print the Chinese character? var encoded = utf8.encode("檯號： 1");
    g.drawString(ttf, 20.0, '$encoded', 10.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM, top - 10.0 * PDFPageFormat.MM);

Answer (score -1):

for images, they might be base64 encoded refer to this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65146858/4412553

```
Image.memory(base64.decode('base64EncodedImageString')),
```