# How to get bytes of a String in Dart?

Tags: string, dart, byte, encode

How can I read the bytes of a `String` in dart?
in Java it is possible through the `String` method `getBytes()`.

[See example](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-getbytes-method-example/)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';

String foo = 'Hello world';
List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(foo);
print(bytes);
```

> Output: [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

Also, if you want to convert back:

```
String bar = utf8.decode(bytes);
```

Comment: nice! but remember add import 'dart:convert';

Answer (score 16):

There is a `codeUnits` getter that returns `UTF-16`

```
String foo = 'Hello world';
List<int> bytes = foo.codeUnits;
print(bytes);
```

> [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

and `runes` that returns Unicode code-points

```
String foo = 'Hello world';
// Runes runes = foo.runes;
// or
Iterable<int> bytes = foo.runes;
print(bytes.toList());
```

> [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

Comment: Yup the differences will only show when you use multi-byte characters, but I don't know your use case and I don't know what `getBytes()` does exactly. I thought alternative options would at least be interesting to know ;-)

Comment: I just tried utf8.encode() of the package 'dart:convert'  and I get the desired result..E.G: print("哔".runes.length) return -> 1 byte, instead print(utf8.encode("哔").length) return -> 3 byte

Comment: `utf8.encode()` returns individual bytes `[229, 147, 148]`, my variants return `[21716]`. Is this what you actually wanted because you accepted my answer?

Comment: sorry, i'm wrong ... yours is a  alternative options  for other contexts. thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for bytes in the form of `Uint8List`, use

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

var string = 'foo';
Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(string));
```

Answer (score 2):

For images they might be base64 encoded, use

```
Image.memory(base64.decode('base64EncodedImageString')),
```

import function from

```
import 'dart:convert';
```